# AES: encrypt using CCCrypt() method and decrypt using C#, the output is wrong

Tags: c#, macos, encryption, aes

Use `CCCrypt()` method to encrypt, and then decrypt it in C#. But the output is not same as the original plain text.

The key is 256 bits long, and the IV is the default value.

The main codes is showing as below:

```
// Encrypt
{
    // the key is 32 bytes （256 bits）.
    Byte iv[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,        // Operation
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128, // Algorithm
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, // Option
                                      keyPtr,                // key
                                      kCCKeySizeAES256,      // key length
                                      iv, /* initialization vector (optional) */
                                      [self bytes],    // plain text
                                      dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted); //dataOutMove
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];
}

// Decrypted
{
    byte[] _key1 = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };
    public static string AESDecrypt(string encryptedString, string key)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.IV = _key1;
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Convert Base64 strings to byte array
        byte[] src = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);

        // decryption
        using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found the reason is the `keyPtr`. In the Encrypt process, I handle the key early like this:

```
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding) [key
getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr)
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now, I modify those codes like this:

```
NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger keyLength = [keyData length];
Byte *keyPtr= (Byte *)malloc(keyLength);
memcpy(keyPtr, [keyData bytes], keyLength);
```

Then I got the correct output. 
Although the problem is gone, I really do not know what's wrong about the previous version.

Comment: Is _key1 in C# the same constant as the IV in OSX?

Comment: Yes, IV is the same constant.

Comment: What about keyPtr, is that an UTF8 string as byte array in OSX, too?

Comment: @GateLuma The part where you go wrong is that you handle the key as a string. Passwords are strings, keys are not, they are byte arrays (or `NSData` in your environment). They may contain *any* byte value, including zero. Handling them as string will get you into trouble when it comes to invalid encodings and characters that are non-printable. On the other hand, if your key does not look like bytes with random values, then you are doing things wrong. Look up PBKDF2 or generate truly random keys.

Comment: @owlstead I have convert the string to bytes before using to cryption, just like the edited version above. And I use the guid generated randomly as the key.

Comment: You should not restrict your keys to character encoding only. Furthermore, malloc() does not say anything about the values of the bytes within the allocated memory. So having any value other than precisely the key size will raise all kinds of hell. *If you have an answer to your own question, then* ***post it as an answer*** *, don't edit it into your question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crypto is designed to fail badly if there is even a small error.  You need to check explicitly that the keys are byte for byte the same (check bytes, not characters).  The same for the IVs.  You are decoding in CBC mode.  Are you certain that the encryption is in CBC mode; it isn't set explicitly in your code.  The same with padding.  Are you certain that the encryption method is using PKCS7?

In general don't rely on default settings, but set them explicitly in your code.

As a last point, are you using the same byte <-> character conversions on both sides.  Again it is better to explicitly state what you are using.  For example, UTF-8 text may come with an initial BOM that a UTF-8 conversion will ignore, but a different conversion will include in the bytes.

Comment: I have solved the problem, and I edited the question. However, I don't know the real season cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some code I was reviewing - where data encrypted by CCCrypt, and decrypted by another tool - did not result in the same plaintext. I tracked it down to a failure to generate the Key properly. It's this line:

```
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If the CString version of "key" is longer than kCCKeySizeAES256 bytes, then key:getCString will return "NO" (because it won't fit in the buffer provided) and will not touch the buffer pointed to by keyPtr, resulting in a key that is effectively all NUL bytes (from the bzero function).

Your replacement code, using [key dataUsingEncoding] does not suffer this problem, as it will create a NSData object as big as needed to store the string. However, it WILL suffer the problem of a key not big enough, unless you can guarantee that the incoming key is long enough.

Using plain text keys is not recommended. If you have a plain text "passphrase", then use a Key derivation function to turn that into a binary sequence. The "gold standard" is PBKDF2, but even doing a SHA2-256 is better than feeding in plain text. SHA2-256 will give you 32 bytes. (SHA-1 is insufficient, as it's only 20 bytes).